Framerate drops on video playback when graphic acceleration is disabled and black video if enabled
I have a M2 Mac Mini. I use this primarily for editing and watching content.
With services like Disney+ Hotstar and JioCinema  and other streaming services, in most of the Videos, the playback shows a black screen with audio only. This is observed in all chromium and safari brwosers.
On Chromium browsers, I am able to view the video by disabling Graphic Acceleration but the framerate starts dropping a lot on all videos. This option is not available on Safari browser.
What is the ideal solution here, so that I can view the video without the frame drops?
